# Symfony2: fos_user_bundle embedding registration form with entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've got 3 entities:
- overriden User
- Address
- Company

User Entity got entity fields Address and Company.

Now I'm trying to build User Registration Form using as well fields from Address and Company entities. The problem is - I have no idea how to proceed with this.

I was trying to do sth like this:

```
 $this->addCommonFields($builder);
    $builder
        ->add('company', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'street',
            'class' => 'AcmePsoBundle:Company',
            'property' => 'street',
        ));
```

but then I receive dropdown list and it supposed to be textfield.

@Edit: Should I use DataTransformer?

Answer (score 0):

You should create new form type for your AcmePsoBundle:Company entity, and use it as:

```
$builder->add('company', new YourCompanyFormType());
```

YourCompanyFormType.php example:

```
class YourCompanyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'street',
            'text'
        );
    }
```

And don't forget to set empty Company to new user entity $user->setCompany(new Company()); before form.